# Method of forcing Windows to update file access times *now*?

Tags: windows, file, time

On Windows XP, the OS will update file access times (if enabled, and it is on my system).

But...according to Microsoft:
   "The NTFS file system delays updates to the last access time 
   for a file by up to 1 hour after the last access."
...and that doesn't just mean "delays updating disk-resident structures" ... no, for
some period after accessing a file then "last access time" will appear as it was before the access.  Sometimes for seconds, sometimes for many minutes (haven't seen an hour yet).

Is there a way ("flush", "sync", or some utility or function) where I can tell Windows XP: hey, update all those unupdated file access times *now*?

I'm trying to determine how some old code works by tracking the files it accesses ... easy to do on most other OS's, but not Windows.  (Yes, I'll also be using ProcMon.)

(I haven't researched this behaviour in newer versions of Windows yet.)

thanks,
Stan

Comment: Tried "sync" from SysInternals ... it doesn't help (i.e., does not cause the file access times to be updated).

Comment: Closing the handle doesn't do it?

Comment: No.  I should have stated that, sorry.  The files are closed, the application is closed, and I've been checking with "dir /ta", and with an Explorer window (with file access time column enabled), and with various "stat()"-type API functions.  Earlier today, some files got updated within a few minutes.  Now, it's been 30 minutes with no update  (still within the hour window, of course :)

Comment: This is not how it works.  It delays *updating the disk*, it still reports the correct LAT from memory.  Check the description of the fsutil.exe [disablelastaccess parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785435%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I have no problems with it not updating the disk ... and one can argue that it is updating some structure somewhere (indeed, it presumably is, since the dates eventually make it to disk).  But.  And this is the important part.  Whatever Windows is doing, the *CORRECT* access time is *NOT* available to API calls for some time after it should be.  Indeed, I have one trace that shows the time hasn't yet been updated after 3 and 1/3 hours (far beyond the 1 hour   mentioned by Microsoft).

Comment: BTW, Hans, "disablelastaccess" is documented as affecting whether or not *directories* get their access time updated, not files.  But, even so, it is enabled on my test systems.  And, in the page you cite, it says disk-resident structures get updated within an hour (as I quoted in my original post :).  The problem is, at least for files (haven't tested directories), the *file* access time is *NOT* updated in a manner even vaguely reasonable.  I'm giving up on using it as a tool.

Comment: I'm in need of the exact same thing. I have to identify the last accessed files from a big directory subtree in order to include only those in an archive. It's baffling that this can't be done. SOme time ago I wrote some code that reacts on any change within a directory subtree, the .NET framewrok offers that. If .NET offers a way to react when a file/dir is also accessed within a subtree, then I can code it up ... my free time is scarce now though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [this answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/556818/5186) that explains that fsutil can be used to disable the update delay on NTFS, at the cost of performance.

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
```

You have to reboot the system for the change to take effect [(source)](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/).